# Removing duplicates from the Google Apps Script ScriptDB

Tags: mongodb, google-apps-script, google-apps, nosql

Due to the recent [issues with the Google Apps Script ScriptDB](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3165) we have ended up with many duplicate records in the ScriptDB.

We have an app that retrieves data from an external system, and stores in ScriptDB if that data doesn't already exist. But due to the recent issues with ScriptDB that check for existence was failing. And our script was continually adding the same data. How can we go and clean up the duplicates? We just want one single copy of each data record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to recreate many bds too because of that appscript bug.
I deleted the entire bd and recreated it by hand because I dont trust the possibly still corrupted entries. 
If its not huge you can dump it on a spreadsheet and manually remove them, then recreate the bd.
Its not just dups, you could also have similar objects as they got recreated and later only one gets updated.

Comment: Well I have 100s of thousands of entries. So re-creating the DB is not really an option......

Comment: Dont use scriptdb for anything that large or anything critical. Its not the first time that google causes irreversible corruption in scriptdb.

Comment: I am sure Google is working on to improve the ScriptDB service. I think it is an excellent service with lot of potential.

Answer (score 1):

If you assigned your own unique IDs to entries in the database, then you can iterate through all possible IDs looking for IDs that have more than 1 entry. I'm not going to write the whole code, but this is a general outline:

```
1. Generate an array of all possible IDs
2. For each ID in array, query ScriptDB for items with that ID
3. If results.length > 1, remove the extras
4. Goto 2
5. Finish
```

Of course, this will take longer than 6 minutes with 100s of thousands of records, so you need some code to save/load state. I use ScriptProperties to save where I am in an array. Then I have a function to determine if I've reached 5.5 minutes, at which point I stop to avoid the "Exceeded maximum execution time" error.

If you don't already use unique IDs, then that'd be a bit more logic to add to your DB save functions in order to prevent this in the future.

Comment: yes, we do have a alpha-number unique ID for each record. can you please provide some code to achieve what you proposed? thanks.